# Xcode breakpoints: break on string compare

Tags: xcode, debugging, conditional-breakpoint

I can do conditional breaks in Xcode using string compare?

something like: `theLabel.text.range(of:"4") != nil`

Comment: At what moment(s) do you want that expression evaluated?

Comment: I'd like to set it in the normal Xcode breakpoint fields, so evaluated everything the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: Cool. So did you try setting a conditional breakpoint? Double-click the breakpoint indicator and enter the expression you want evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing a conditional breakpoint. Double-click the breakpoint marker and enter the expression you want evaluated. You will break only if the expression is true.

Be sure to test your expression in code, first, to make sure it is valid. In your case, you need to remember that `text` is an Optional:

[image]

Comment: So I can use valid swift statements for the conditionals. Great!,